# Matrices with a certain property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix having the following properties

- $A$ is invertible
- all the entries in $A$ are either $-1$, $0$, or $1$
- if a column has more than one non-zero entry, then the non-zero entries are strictly below the diagonal

Suppose $A^{-1}$ has the same properties. Does it follow that every row and column in $A$ must contain exactly one entry which is $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Beyond permutations of diagonal matrices, do you have any nontrivial examples of such $A$?

Comment: I think there are plenty of non-trivial examples. For exmple $a_{21}=a_{31}=a_{12}=a_{31}=1$, and the rest are zero, for a $3\times 3$ matrix. The strong requirement is for the inverse to have the same properties.

Comment: I don’t understand your example, given the repeat of $a_{31}$. Even if you meant $a_{13}$ , neither are invertible. I’m asking for a matrix that satisfies all the criteria of $A$ including the inverse criteria.

Comment: @AlexR.Wouldn't any orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix with all entries as either $0,1$ or $-1$ work?

Comment: @Epiksalad Typo on my part. I meant $a_{21}=a_{31}=a_{12}=a_{33}=1$. This satisfies all the conditions without being a permutation matrix.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. $A^{-1}$ doesn't satisfy all the criteria. I've got to the point where I can say that the $n^{th}$ and $(n-1)^{th}$ rows and columns of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ must contain exactly one non-zero entry.

Comment: @Epiksalad: they wouldn’t obviously satisfy the below diagonal criteria for both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ except in the trivial diagonal case or permutations of it. Unless I’m missing an obvious subclass of them

Comment: Sorry, now I see what you asked, confusion on my part. I believe any signed permutation matrix satisfies these criteria. I am asking whether these are the only ones.

Comment: @Markus: sure I think we’re on the same page then. Curiously, where did this question arise, or in what context?

Comment: @AlexR. Oh, okay, sorry, I became confused for a moment. Any signed permutation matrix would satisfy all the criteria.

Comment: @AlexR.It came from a combinatorics problem, which reduced to some linear transformations satisfying these properties being a signed permutation. Seems true, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Does not the determinant in such a matrix reduce to 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We shall adopt the following notations. Let $B=A^{-1}$. Denote the standard basis by $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and the identity matrix by $\mathbf I$. When not in bold face, the letter $I$ denotes an index set. For any matrix $M$, denote its $i$-th row by $M_{i\ast}$ and its $j$-th column by $M_{\ast j}$. When $I$ and $J$ are index sets, $M_{IJ},\ M_{iJ}$ and $M_{Ij}$ are notations for submatrix, sub row vector and sub column vector of $M$ respectively. We call a **nonzero** element $m_{ij}$ a *right entry* of $M$ if $j\ge i$ or a *left entry* if $i>j$.

By the given conditions, $A$ satisfies the following properties:

**Property 1.** $A$ cannot contain both right and left entries on the same column. If $a_{ij}$ is a right entry, $A_{\ast j}$ is a scalar multiple of $e_i$.

*Proof.* This follows directly from the third given condition.

**Property 2.** Each row of $A$ contains at most one right entry.

*Proof.* Suppose $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ik}$ are two right entries of $A$. By property 1, both $A_{\ast j}$ and $A_{\ast k}$ are scalar multiples of $e_i$. Hence $j$ must be equal to $k$ because $A$ is invertible.

**Property 3.** Every column of $A$ contains at most one left entry.

*Proof.* Suppose the contrary that $A$ has more than one left entries on some column $j$. Let $K=\{k: a_{kj}\ne0\}$. Then $|K|>1$ and by property 1, $a_{kj}$ is a left entry of $A$ and $b_{jk}$ is either zero or a right entry of $B$ for each $k\in K$. Since $BA=\mathbf I$, we have
$$
B_{\ast K}A_{Kj} = BA_{\ast j} = (BA)_{\ast j} = e_j.\tag{1}
$$
In particular, $B_{jK}A_{Kj}=1$. Since $A_{Kj}$ is entrywise nonzero, we must have $b_{jk_0}\ne0$ for some $k_0\in K$, meaning that $b_{jk_0}$ is a right entry of $B$. Therefore, $b_{jk_0}$ is the only nonzero entry on $B_{\ast k_0}$ by property 1 and also the only nonzero entry on $B_{jK}$ by property 2. In other words, $B_{\ast K}$ is in the form of
$$
B_{\ast K}=\pmatrix{\ast&0&\ast\\ 0&b_{jk_0}&0\\ \ast&0&\ast}.\tag{2}
$$
Let $I=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{j\}$ and $J=K\setminus\{k_0\}$. As $|K|>1$, $J$ is non-empty. Then $(1)$ and $(2)$ together imply that $A_{Jj}$ is a non-trivial solution of $B_{IJ}A_{Jj}=0$. Thus $B_{IJ}$ and in turn $B_{\ast J}$ have linearly dependent columns, and we arrive at a contradiction because $B$ is supposed to be invertible. $\square$

Now properties 1 and 3 imply that $A$ has at most one nonzero entry on each column. It follows from the invertibility of $A$ that $A$ has exactly one nonzero entry on each row and each column, i.e. $A=DP$ for some permutation matrix $P$ and some invertible diagonal matrix $D$.

Answer (score 0):

I think only permutations of diagonal matrices are valid solutions. First, $A$ must have nonzero entries in each column as otherwise it’s not invertible. Next, $A$ must have at least one column with exactly one nonzero entry, as otherwise $A$ is lower triangular with 0s on the diagonal so that its determinent would be 0. Finally for column with a single nonzero entry, no two such columns can have nonzero elements in the same row due to linear dependence.

Split $A$ into columns with exactly one nonzero value (X) or more than one (Y). Since the single nonzero columns (X) cannot share a nonzero row, you can column- permute them (leaving Y untouched) so that the resulting matrix is lower triangular, i.e permute $X$ to be in descending order relative to each nonzero element in $X$. So the determinant must be zero, unless $Y$ is empty.

It follows that $A$ can only have columns with exactly one nonzero entry.

Comment: I did not understand how you can column-permute them to make it diagonal except for the $Y$ columns. If you have, say, the $n^{th}$ and $(n-1)^{th}$ row satisfying the $X$ criteria, how can you guarantee being able to column permute them, leaving the first $n-2$ columns untouched, such that those two columns have the non-zero elements along the diagonal? (I took column-permute to mean that you permute the $X$ columns among themselves.)

Comment: @Epiksalad: you should be able to always put the columns of $X$ in descending order relative to their nonzero element. This necessarily implies that the resulting matrix, e.g putting back $Y$, is lower triangular. Perhaps saying diagonal is too strong, so I’ve removed that implication.